# .net non ascii username passwords

Tags: sql-server, unicode, passwords

in my web site (c# & sql server) i am trying to enable non ascii username and passwords,
(username and password columns are set to NvarChar )

what would be the best aproach to achive this?

Comment: I hope you read this - "string is a collection of unicode characters".

Comment: please read my reply to John Saunders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you must not have tried this yet.

.NET strings are Unicode. There should be nothing special you have to do.

---

Try

```
select * from site_users where un=N'محبوب' and pw=N'محبوب'
```

Comment: i have with post and get. I have manually entered محبوب as username and pw to my table and tried with post and get in get محبوب gets url encoded and i would expect it may not work but in post method result was same. then i tried query with sql management studio 

select * from site_users where un='محبوب' and pw='محبوب'

it didn't return any result too

Comment: sorry would you mind checking this. i got below code to pass paramater to sp, although direct select with N work when i pass string to sqp it doesnt

..snip..
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@un", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = un;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@pw", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pw;
..snip..

Comment: please igonere my last reply. it was my mistake. forgot to set @un to nvarchar

Comment: No problem. You found it yourself quickly enough!